# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Entity metadata for Category#products was not found

Tags: mysql, node.js, web, typeorm

I looked at other issues that throw the same error, but none of then worked for me. I tried rename, import, put in config file, I read the typeorm doc a thousand times but I can't find the solution. Can anyone help me?

On ormconfig.json:

```
  "entities": [
    "./src/models/*.ts"
  ],
```

Category entity:

```
  import {
  Column,
  Entity,
  JoinColumn,
  ManyToOne,
  OneToMany,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
} from 'typeorm';
import Product from './Product';
import User from './User';

@Entity('categories')
class Category {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;
  @Column('varchar')
  name: string;
  @Column('varchar')
  description?: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, categories => Category)
  @JoinColumn()
  user: User;

  @OneToMany(() => Product, product => product.category)
  products: Product[];
}
export default Category;
```

Product entity:

```
import { PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, ManyToOne, JoinColumn } from 'typeorm';
import Category from './Category';
import Model from './Model';
import Provider from './Provider';
import User from './User';

export enum Genre {
  FEMALE = 'F',
  MALE = 'M',
}

export enum Size {
  PP = 'PP',
  P = 'P',
  M = 'M',
  G = 'G',
  GG = 'GG',
  SIZE_33 = '33',
  SIZE_34 = '34',
  SIZE_35 = '35',
  SIZE_36 = '36',
  SIZE_37 = '37',
  SIZE_38 = '38',
  SIZE_39 = '39',
  SIZE_40 = '40',
  SIZE_41 = '41',
  SIZE_42 = '42',
  SIZE_43 = '43',
  SIZE_44 = '44',
  SIZE_45 = '45',
  SIZE_46 = '46',
  SIZE_47 = '47',
  SIZE_48 = '48',
  SIZE_49 = '49',
  SIZE_50 = '50',
  SIZE_51 = '51',
  SIZE_52 = '52',
}

export enum Status {
  IN_STOCK = 'I',
  OUTPUT = 'O',
}

enum Purchase_type {
  CONSIGNED = 'C',
  OWNER = 'O',
}
class Product {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;
  @Column('varchar')
  name: string;
  @Column('enum')
  genre: Genre;
  @Column('varchar')
  color: string;
  @Column('enum')
  size: Size;
  @Column('enum')
  status: Status;
  @Column('datetime')
  created_at: Date;
  @Column('varchar')
  id_photo?: string;
  @Column('varchar')
  obs?: string;
  @Column('float')
  sale_value: number;
  @Column('float')
  purchase_value: number;
  @Column('enum')
  purchase_type: Purchase_type;
  @Column('varchar')
  brand: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, user => user.products)
  @JoinColumn()
  user: User;

  @ManyToOne(() => Provider, provider => provider.products)
  @JoinColumn()
  provider: Provider;

  @ManyToOne(() => Category, category => category.products)
  category: Category;

  @ManyToOne(() => Model, model => model.products)
  @JoinColumn()
  model: Model;
}
export default Product;
```

The error:

(node:10691) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Entity metadata for Category#products was not found. Check if you specified a correct entity object and if it's connected in the connection options.
at /home/guilherme/Documentos/Restore/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:664:23
at Array.forEach ()
at EntityMetadataBuilder.computeInverseProperties (/home/guilherme/Documentos/Restore/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:659:34)
at /home/guilherme/Documentos/Restore/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:118:56
at Array.forEach ()
at EntityMetadataBuilder.build (/home/guilherme/Documentos/Restore/src/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:118:25)
at ConnectionMetadataBuilder.buildEntityMetadatas (/home/guilherme/Documentos/Restore/src/connection/ConnectionMetadataBuilder.ts:66:111)
at Connection.buildMetadatas (/home/guilherme/Documentos/Restore/src/connection/Connection.ts:517:59)
at Connection. (/home/guilherme/Documentos/Restore/src/connection/Connection.ts:193:18)
at step (/home/guilherme/Documentos/Restore/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:141:27)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seems you forgot Entity for product entity

```
import { PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, ManyToOne, JoinColumn,  Entity } from 'typeorm';
import Category from './Category';
import Model from './Model';
import Provider from './Provider';
import User from './User';

@Entity('products') // you forget this 
class Product {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;
  @Column('varchar')
  name: string;
  @Column('enum')
  genre: Genre;
  @Column('varchar')
  color: string;
  @Column('enum')
  size: Size;
  @Column('enum')
  status: Status;
  @Column('datetime')
  created_at: Date;
  @Column('varchar')
  id_photo?: string;
  @Column('varchar')
  obs?: string;
  @Column('float')
  sale_value: number;
  @Column('float')
  purchase_value: number;
  @Column('enum')
  purchase_type: Purchase_type;
  @Column('varchar')
  brand: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, user => user.products)
  @JoinColumn()
  user: User;

  @ManyToOne(() => Provider, provider => provider.products)
  @JoinColumn()
  provider: Provider;

  @ManyToOne(() => Category, category => category.products)
  category: Category;

  @ManyToOne(() => Model, model => model.products)
  @JoinColumn()
  model: Model;
}
export default Product;
```